# Yii: How to create 2 input fieds by 1 table field?

Tags: php, yii

That I need: 
 `form.created_from`, `form.created_to` => `table.created BETWEEN <form.created_from> AND <form.created_to>`

```
#table model
class SomeModel extends CActiveRecord {
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'id' => 'ID',
            'created' => 'Created',
        );
    }
}
#form model
class SomeModelForm extends CFormModel {
    public $id;
    public $createdFrom;
    public $createdTo;
}
#controller
class SomeController extends Controller {
    public function actionSomeAction() {
       $model = SomeModel('SomeModelForm');
    }
}
```

ERROR: **Exception: Property "SomeModel.createdFrom" is not defined.** 

Is it possible to do that without defining unusefull properties (`createdFrom`, `createdTo`) in `SomeModel` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#form model
class SomeModelForm extends CFormModel {
    public $id;
    public $createdFrom;
    public $createdTo;
    public function search()
    {
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
        $criteria->compare('id', $this->id);
        $criteria->addBetweenCondition('created', $this->createdFrom, $this->createdTo);
        return new CActiveDataProvider(SomeModel::model(), array(
            'criteria' => $criteria,
        ));
    }
}

#controller
class SomeController extends Controller {
    public function actionSomeAction() {
       $model = SomeModelForm();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this, I hope it works:

```
$model = new SomeModelForm;
$model->attributes = $_POST['SomeModelForm'];

$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->addBetweenCondition('created', $model->createdFrom, $model->createdTo);
$result = SomeModel::model()->findAll($criteria);
```